# JQuery - data-size attribute returns 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of images, that need data-size attribute applied to img tag for each image

```
<div class="wrapper">

      <div class="col-md-3>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="img/1.jpg">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="img/1.jpg">
            </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="img/2.jpg">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="img/2.jpg">
            </a>
        </div>
      </div>

</div>
```

Here is my jquery code:

```
$('.wrapper').each(function() {
  $(this).find('a').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('data-size', $(this).find('img').get(0).naturalWidth + 'x' + $(this).find('img').get(0).naturalHeight);
  });
});
```

But it always returns data-size="0x0"
Could someone please explain, if i'm doing anything wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Probably the image hasn't loaded yet as of when the code runs.

Comment: Side note, that code can be a fair bit simpler: https://pastebin.com/683SCuu2

Comment: Is `$(this).find('img').width()` returning 0 also?

Comment: Thanks for comments! The problem seems to be, that images are not loaded before, as when I refresh the page, data-size is correct. Sorry, I'm not really competent in js